# Eclipse JSF anotations managed beans code completion

Tags: jsf, javabeans, glassfish-3, managed, code-completion

My question was asked on this forum, but the answer didn't completely satisfy my situation.
In JSF 2.0 one could declare in the beans annotations like `@ManagedBean` or `@ManagedBean(name="blah")` and the scope of the bean instead of declaring them in `faces-config.xml` and use the beans in `*.xhtml, *.jsp` etc.

BUT, here is my question, the code completion in Eclipse doesn't work if you declare using annotations. It only works if one declares the beans in `faces-config.xml`.
Another post in the forum does give an answer: JBoss Tools, but I couldn't find if it works with GlassFish.

I use Eclipse Indigo Java EE and GlassFish. It should work if I install it ? or there is another more compatible way.

Thank you for your time and happy coding!

---

The details:

```
Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
  Software being installed: JBoss Tools JSF 3.3.0.v20120302-0331-H69-Beta1 (org.jboss.tools.jsf.feature.feature.group 3.3.0.v20120302-0331-H69-Beta1)
  Software currently installed: Oracle GlassFish Server Tools 1.8.0.201110200920 (oracle.eclipse.tools.indigo.glassfish.feature.group 1.8.0.201110200920)
  Only one of the following can be installed at once: 
    Server UI 1.1.305.v20110511 (org.eclipse.wst.server.ui 1.1.305.v20110511)
    Server UI 1.1.207.v20110119 (org.eclipse.wst.server.ui 1.1.207.v20110119)
    Server UI 1.3.0.v20120210_1439 (org.eclipse.wst.server.ui 1.3.0.v20120210_1439)
    Server UI 1.1.306.v20110823_1704 (org.eclipse.wst.server.ui 1.1.306.v20110823_1704)
    Server UI 1.1.209.v20110914_1539 (org.eclipse.wst.server.ui 1.1.209.v20110914_1539)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Oracle GlassFish Server Tools 4.1.0.201110200920 (oracle.eclipse.tools.glassfish 4.1.0.201110200920)
    To: bundle org.eclipse.wst.server.ui [1.1.305,1.2.0)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Oracle GlassFish Server Tools 1.8.0.201110200920 (oracle.eclipse.tools.indigo.glassfish.feature.group 1.8.0.201110200920)
    To: oracle.eclipse.tools.glassfish [4.1.0.201110200920]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: WST Server UI 3.3.2.v20111026_1748-7B79FBdAtJcez0EONePJUSNPjBC42 (org.eclipse.wst.server_ui.feature.feature.group 3.3.2.v20111026_1748-7B79FBdAtJcez0EONePJUSNPjBC42)
    To: org.eclipse.wst.server.ui [1.3.0.v20120210_1439]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Eclipse Web Developer Tools 3.3.2.v201111030500-7O7IFj6EMjB7yO1Xs_G1kMtQeOye6HTXFWve95_R (org.eclipse.wst.web_ui.feature.feature.group 3.3.2.v201111030500-7O7IFj6EMjB7yO1Xs_G1kMtQeOye6HTXFWve95_R)
    To: org.eclipse.wst.server_ui.feature.feature.group [3.3.2.v20111026_1748-7B79FBdAtJcez0EONePJUSNPjBC42]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: JBoss Tools JSF 3.3.0.v20120302-0331-H69-Beta1 (org.jboss.tools.jsf.feature.feature.group 3.3.0.v20120302-0331-H69-Beta1)
    To: org.eclipse.wst.web_ui.feature.feature.group 3.3.2
```

Comment: The details: Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency. Software being installed: JBoss Tools JSF 3.3.0.v20120302-0331-H69-Beta1 (org.jboss.tools.jsf.feature.feature.group 3.3.0.v20120302-0331-H69-Beta1) Software currently installed: Oracle GlassFish Server Tools 1.8.0.201110200920 (oracle.eclipse.tools.indigo.glassfish.feature.group 1.8.0.201110200920) Only one of the following can be installed at once: Server UI 1.1.305.v20110511 (org.eclipse.wst.server.ui 1.1.305.v20110511) Server UI 1.1.207.v20110119 (org.eclipse.wst.server.ui 1.1.207.v20110119) Server UI 1.3.0.v20120

Comment: try out the version for helios http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/updates/stable/helios/ (on your indigo eclipse)

Comment: but the jboss for helios is compatible with the new indigo?

Comment: I did a double check in my eclipse , although I'm 99% sure that previously I did installed the Helios version on my Indigo eclipse I can see that the current JBoss Tolls version on my Indigo is the "Indigo version of Jboss Tools" , I'd say extract a fresh copy of eclipse Indigo and try to add the Jboss Tools on it...That way You might get idea on why you cant apply it to your current Eclipse

Comment: currently I`m at work, so I can`t try it. I will try to install first the helios version of JBoss and if it doesn`t work than I will try on a fresh copy of indigo the indigo version of JBoss.
If I install any version of JBoss the plugin doesn`t mess with my other installations and configurations?

Comment: And another thing: I install the hole JBoss Web and Java EE Development package or just the JBoss Tools JSF?

Comment: backup you eclipse folder before all those attempt's , what you need to select from the package is Web and Java EE Development

Comment: by the way , next time Re-Edit your original Question instead of posting "details" as an answer....

Comment: 1/2 h I am at home and currently I try installing it. I have installed what I could from Web and Java EE Development (everything except Jboss Portlet and Hibernate Tools)...it changed a little bit my project but the core remained the same. It asked me to add JSF capabilities, I added them and nothing. The project works but no code completion at the managed beans.

Comment: the code completion is in the xhtml pages... like #{myBean.myMethodName} or #{myBean.AttributeName}

Comment: Yes, in the *.xhtml at the #{ and I press Ctrl + Space and in the list I want to have the beans I declared @ManagedBean and @(Request, Session, etc.)Scope, and put a dot then again Ctrl + Space and in the list I have the atributes , methods and put a }. Like if I put the beans in faces-config.xml. The normal Java code completion.
The rest of the Web and Java EE Development package that I could install is enought for the code completation to work?

Comment: haven't understand what you are saying , but , Yes the Web and Java EE Development should enable the code completion in xhtml pages

Comment: :)I just described the code completation at #{myBean.myMethodName}. Let me put it in another way (I`m sorry but as you can see English is not my native language): I couldn`t install the hole "Web and Java EE Develpment" package. I managed to install everything except JBoss Portlet and Hibernate Tools. These 2 gived me conflicting dependencies.
The packages I managed to install are enough to activate the code completation?

Comment: Ok, thank you very much, I will try again. I must have overlooked something...I hope it will work. Again thank you!

Comment: As Daniel has mentioned, please use the edit link to add new information to your question instead of posting it as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JBoss Tools (at least for the code completion part) are working with the Eclipse IDE (Integrated development environment)

It has nothing to do with the Web Server you choose...

So Yes, it should work with your Eclipse (GlassFish/Tomcat etc... has no affect on it...)

Comment: I wasn`t sure of compatibility. I thought that maybe it works with JBoss Web server. Thank you!

Comment: nope , it has nothing to do with JBoss Web server. its (at least the code completion part)  meant to integrate only with the IDE (in this case its Eclipse)

Comment: and it works out of the box, the plugin I mean. no further configuration?

Comment: as far as I remember yes , but you should only install the "Web and Java EE Development"

Comment: know I tried, but I incountered some problems. At the Available Software I entered http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/updates/development/indigo/ and I`ve got at the end of the list "JBoss Web and Java EE Development". I`ve tried to install it and it gives me "The operation cannot be completed. See the details" 
The details:

Comment: know I tried, but I incountered some problems. At the Available Software I entered http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/updates/development/indigo/ and I`ve got at the end of the list "JBoss Web and Java EE Development". I`ve tried to install it and it gives me "The operation cannot be completed. See the details" 
Conflicting dependencies...the errors are too long for the post

And even if I select just JBossTools JSF from JBoss Web and Development it gives me the same error.

Comment: I installed a fresh copy of Indigo and I installed te JBoss Web and Java EE Development for indigo  AND AFTER that I`ve installed GlashFish and it worked like a charm. 
After that I returned on my original indigo eclipse and I`ve tried to uninstall the GlassFish because that is why I couldn`t install JBoss. The order is important somehow initially you have to install JBoss and after GlassFish. But Know :) I can`t unistall completely GlassFish...

Comment: never mind. I will use the new installation. Thank you for everything! You helped me a lot! Thank you!